# How to make generic method for DbSets?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have many simular meyhod like this two:

```
    public static List<MyCatalogViewModel> LoadCatalog1(...)
    {
       var catalog= DbContext.MyContexClass1.Where(t => !t.Deleted).Select(k=> new MyCatalogViewModel{ Id= k.Id, Name = k.Name}).ToList();
       return catalog;
    }

    public static List<MyCatalogViewModel> LoadCatalog2(...)
    {
       var catalog= DbContext.MyContexClass2.Where(t => !t.Deleted).Select(k=> new MyCatalogViewModel{ Id= k.Id, Name = k.Name}).ToList();
       return catalog;
    }
```

Here is i take data from `DbContext`. Difference only in `DBSet<>`.
How can i make a generic method instead of this methods?

Classes `MyContexClass2` and `MyContexClass1` both have a properties `Id` and `Name`. And looks like:

```
public partial class MyContexClass1: AccountableDbObject
{
    public MyContexClass1()
    {
      <..some code..>
    }

    public override int Id{ get; internal set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

     <...Another properties...>
}
```

Comment: Do the items in the `MyContextClass1` and `MyContextClass2` implement a common interface that exposes `Id` and `Name` properties?

Comment: @Asad I'd update question please look at it.

Comment: Yes, I can see that both of them independently have the `Id` and `Name` properties. What you need is for these properties to be defined in a type that both `MyContexClass1` and 2 implement/inherit, so that you can write your code against a single interface and pass in members of either DBSet.

Comment: Eg. if you had an interface `INamedAndIdentified` with gettable `Name` and `Id` properties, and both `MyContexClass1` and 2 implemented this interface, you could do: `DbContext.MyContexClass1.Cast<INamedAndIdentified>().Concat(DbContext.MyContexClass2)...` followed by the rest of your method chain as you have it, and that would deal with both `DbSets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DbContext` has a [`Set<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.113).aspx) method that allows retrieving a set of arbitrary entities (aslong as their type is registered with the context).

**Update**

To actually use the properties defined on these generic types, you need the model classes to implement a common interface:

```
public interface ICatalogItem { //or some other name 
      bool Deleted { get; }
      int Id { get; }
      string Name { get; }
}
```

E.g. your `MyContexClass1` definition would become

```
MyContexClass1 : AccountableDbObject, ICatalogItem
```

Now you can build a generic method that will return the appropriate viewmodels:

```
public static List<MyCatalogViewModel> LoadCatalog<T>()
    where T : class, ICatalogItem
{
   var catalog= DbContext.Set<T>.Where(t => !t.Deleted).Select(k=> new MyCatalogViewModel{ Id= k.Id, Name = k.Name}).ToList();
   return catalog;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a little example?